# Recursion not working in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print a series in python which actually like Fibonacci but instead of adding you have to multiply.

My code is :

```
def robLan(n):
    if n > 3:
        robLan(n -1) * robLan(n - 2)

    elif n == 1:
        return 1

    elif n == 2:
        return 2

    elif n == 3:
        return 2

list = []
for i in range(1,10):
    z =  robLan(i)
    list.append(z)
print list
```

These are the error I get:

```
File "C:\Users\Arjun's\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\List\com\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    z =  robLan(i)
  File "C:\Users\Arjun's\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\List\com\__init__.py", line 3, in robLan
    robLan(n -1) * robLan(n - 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You're missing `return` in the first `if` block.

Answer (score 5):

Your function doesn't return the recursive call:

```
if n > 3:
    robLan(n -1) * robLan(n - 2)
```

Without a return statement here, your function ends without an explicit return and `None` is returned instead:

```
>>> robLan(4) is None
True
```

The above *should* have returned `4` (`roblan(3) * roblan(2)` gives `2 * 2` is `4`). For any starting value of 5 or over the function uses more than one level of recursion and a `None` return value ends up being used for multiplication.

Add `return`:

```
if n > 3:
    return robLan(n - 1) * robLan(n - 2)
```

Your statements can be simplified:

```
def robLan(n):
    if n > 2:
        return robLan(n - 1) * robLan(n - 2)
    return n
```

Your sample loop then generates:

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 32, 256, 8192, 2097152]
```

Answer (score 1):

you should return a value when n > 3

Answer (score 0):

This is complete corrected code:

```
def robLan(n):
    if n > 3:
        return robLan(n -1) * robLan(n - 2)

    elif n == 1:
        return 1

    elif n == 2:
        return 2

    elif n == 3:
        return 2

list = []
for i in range(1,10):
    z =  robLan(i)
    list.append(z)
print list
```